# Bazel testing getting stuck

Tags: python, multiprocessing, bazel

I have a Python codebase with some tests that I am able to run with the `python -m unittest...` command however, when I run the same tests with `bazel test`, the tests just get stuck and time out. One thing to note is that the code is using python's multiprocessing, and also makes a bunch of post requests to an external service.

Using `bazel run` and logging entry points in several parts of the code verifies the code is randomly stuck.

`top` also does not show a lot of resources being used.

Any ideas on how to debug this? Most of the tests are set to `size=large` and have the "exclusive" tag.

Answer (score 0):

The bazel sandbox by default blocks all network requests. You can specify that a given test requires network access by adding the tag `requires-network`.

Alternatively you can add the tag `no-sandbox` to disable the sandbox completely for the given test / action.

It is also possible that network access is disabled by a bazelrc option such as `--modify_execution_info=TestRunner=+block-network` so you might want to check your bazelrc too if the `requires-network` tag doesn't fix the timeouts in the tests.

Comment: I forgot to mention that these are integration tests. And I am not sure if blocked network requests are an issue - as in there are other (unit) tests making network requests which are working just fine. I checked the bazelrc, the only test strategy specified is: `test --strategy=CoreCompile=standalone`

Comment: Another weird thing - the tests passed on CI but continue failing locally